# Can I make "Always trust software from" unchecked by default?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, certificate

While installing an application, I received a prompt to install a driver which had a checked checkbox next to the text "Always trust software from [company]":

[image: "Always trust software from [company]"]

Since there have been instances of [certificates being stolen and used to install malware](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/07/stolen-certificates-from-d-link-used-to-sign-password-stealing-malware/), I consider "always trusting" any certificates (other than the preinstalled ones) poor security practice. Consequently, I always uncheck the checkbox. However, I'd like to not have to do that every time, so:

Is there a Windows setting that makes this checkbox unchecked by default?

Comment: It seems that you could try to use the command: 

certutil -addstore "TrustedPublisher" MyCertificate.cer
RELATED LINK:http://www.migee.com/2010/09/24/solution-for-unattendedsilent-installs-and-would-you-like-to-install-this-device-software/

Comment: @daidai That seems to do the opposite of what I'm asking for.